# Upgrade chef client without Internet access

Tags: chef-infra

I have seen some of the forums and omnibus updater cookbook for upgrading the chef clients, but it all talks about for the nodes which have internet connectivity but in a situation if their is no internet connectivity then how can we fetch the package and upgrade the client. The option we are looking at is to use nexus as artefact management.

Any thoughts.

Answer (score 0):

There's no general solution for so "special" environments. When you already have Nexus in mind, where's the point where you're struggling?

The simplest thing would be to fetch the chef-client package (`.deb`, `.rpm` etc) from your Nexus using `remote_file` and afterwards just install the package using Chef.

It seems that you need a plugin for Nexus to host Debian repos (Artifactory AFAIK supports it out of the box), so you could also just use this for distribution - or however you distribute your other packages.

To kind of repeat.. please describe the actual problem a bit more in detail (after you've tried and failed..)

Comment: We were trying to use the omnibus updater cookbook for upgrading our chef-clients but the challenge we have is that the installers are directly fetched from chef website through internet which is not the feasible as all our servers don't have internet connectivity. In this case we would like to know how and where do we need to modify to use this cookbook with nexus repo.

Comment: You don't have any mechanisms for distributing operating system packages in place?